# Display 4 items per row from any category on magento1.7 home page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am fresher with magento. I am using magento 1.7.

I want to display 4 items per row on magento home from a category. I am using wayaat.com free [theme](http://www.wayaat.com/magento-theme/jewellery-magento-theme.html). How can I display. Please guide.

My dummy magento instance where I am doing R&D with magento: http://questoons.com/magento/

Comment: Now I am displaying category items by adding the code below in CMS > Pages > Home Page in magento.

code: {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different list file for displaying your product, just copy original list.phtml file and give name something like listhome.phtml and put in catalog/product folder and in this file change `$_columnCount` variable to `$_columnCount =4` and you are done and in your cms page change your listing file named `{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/listhome.phtml"}}`

Comment: Many thanks for responding sir. I did what you suggested. I found the list.phtml in the path magento/app/design/frontend/default/jewellery/template/catalog/product. jewellery is the theme directory name. It is still displaying the same as before. What should I do now?

Comment: browser cache or magento cache?

Comment: I cleared both browser and magento cache. But still displaying three items in a row. Nothing happened.

Comment: I can see 4 products, issue is with your css, check in fire bug you can see 4 li tag in one ul tag

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to post an answer here, but i dont have enough reputation to comment.
Increase your ul.products-grid width from current 980px to at least 1001 px. It will bring the forth product in row. As Mufaddal stated before, yours is a matter of css now.